# Excel Time Format

Tags: excel, vba

Having trouble with time formatting.

I have set the cell to custom format 00:00.

Currently in column A a date is inputted, this can be as 0300 which converts to 03:00 which is perfect or you can just enter 03:00.

I now have a problem if a user enters 03;00 as i need this to display 03:00

how can i ensure that all times are in the hh:mm format and not in hh;mm etc.

This needs to auto change on input for anything in column A, except what is the header (A1:A5) although this should not be affected.

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK, a custom format of `00:00` wouldn't be valid.  Do you perhaps mean `hh:mm`?  But if you are using `hh:mm` then entering "0300" would cause Excel to display the time of midnight on day 300 (i.e. 26 October 1900).  Or have you used a format of `00\:00`?  But `00\:00` would cause an entry of "03:00" to be calculated as 0.125 (1/8th of a day) and displayed as "00:00".  I'm afraid that I am confused.

Comment: Why don't you just replace `;` with `:` and run the normal macro that you have?

Comment: Sorry i meant 00\:00 this works fine. @niclas i dont have any macro at present i need one on cell change. ive tried but not sure what im doing is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does what i require.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
Dim xStr As String
Dim xVal As String
Set rng1 = Range("A:A")
Set rng2 = Range("C:C")
Set rng3 = Range("I:I")
On Error GoTo EndMacro
If Application.Intersect(Target, Union(rng1, rng2, rng3)) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Target.Value = "" Then Exit Sub
If Target.Row < 5 Then Exit Sub
Application.EnableEvents = False
With Target
    If Not .HasFormula Then
        Target.Value = Replace(Target.Value, ";", ":")
        Target.Value = Left(Target.Value, 5)
        xVal = .Value
        Select Case Len(xVal)
            Case 1 ' e.g., 1 = 00:01 AM
                xStr = "00:0" & xVal
            Case 2 ' e.g., 12 = 00:12 AM
                xStr = "00:" & xVal
            Case 3 ' e.g., 735 = 07:35 AM
                xStr = "0" & Left(xVal, 1) & ":" & Right(xVal, 2)
            Case 4 ' e.g., 1234 = 12:34
                xStr = Left(xVal, 2) & ":" & Right(xVal, 2)
            Case 5 ' e.g., 12:45 = 12:45
                xStr = Left(xVal, 2) & Mid(xVal, 2, 1) & Right(xVal, 2)
            Case Else
                Err.Raise 0
        End Select
        .Value = Format(TimeValue(xStr), "hh:mm")
    End If
End With
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub
```

EndMacro:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On your sheets change event you would place the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.CountLarge = 1 And Target.Column = 1 And Target.Row > 5 Then
        Target.Value2 = Replace(Target.Value2, ";", ":")
    End If
End Sub
```

Explaining the code... it first checks to make sure that the change isn't on multiple cells (ie paste) and that the change is on column A below Row 5. If it does pass the conditional it simply replaces `;` for `:`.

Comment: Hi nbayly Thanks for your comment. i have tried this, if i enter 0302 the time changes to 03:02 as expected. if i enter 03:02 this now changes to 00:00 which is no good, and if i enter 03;02 it remains the same. have i done something wrong ?

Comment: Ok im getting closer, [code]Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.CountLarge = 1 And Target.Column = 1 And Target.Row > 5 Then
        Target.Value = Replace(Target.Value, ";", ":")
    End If
End Sub

[/code] however i have to remove the cell format, so this now allow 03:02 and converts 03;02 to 03:02 however i now need it so that when i enter 0302 it converts to 03:02

Comment: That proves a lot more difficult than your original ask mainly because the event won't fire until after you enter the value and Excel reformats the number. Are you presetting your cells in column A as Time format? The problem you have is that Excel is trying to interpret and reformat your input so I don't know anyway to find the manual input before Excel does this. Maybe set your column as Text and create a time format validation and then set that cell format to time.

Comment: This seems a bit more extensive than your original ask. If you found my answer suitable to your original question could you kindly mark it as such. You might want to resubmit your followup as a new question to get more eyeballs. Cheers.

Comment: please see below.